# Compositing two images with Ruby Quick_Magick

Tags: ruby

How can one composite two images using the Ruby Quick_Magick gem?

I try:

```
qm_image = QuickMagick::Image.read(type_path.join(image_name).to_s).first
qm_image.composite 0, 0, 0, 0, '/home/ruby/projects/myproject/public/mask1.png'
qm_image.save!
```

I have:

> Error executing command: command
>             Result is: 
>             Error is: Segmentation fault

=== Conclusion:

I solved a problem migrated to Mini_Magick. Thanks for all.

Comment: You get a segmentation fault.
You don't provided any helpful information.
What OS ? Which ruby version, wchich library versions you're using ?

Comment: QuickMagick - 0.8, Linux Debian 6, Ruby 1.9.3, RoR 3.2.9

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
require 'rmagick'

qm_image1 = Magick::Image.read(image_name1).first
qm_image2 = Magick::Image.read(image_name2).first

qm_image_result = qm_image1.composite(qm_image2, 0, 0, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
qm_image_result.write('result.jpg')
```

See http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#composite_bang for the possibe parameters of composite

Comment: quick_magic doesn't have a composite, see http://quickmagick.rubyforge.org/quick_magick/ but if it uses rmagick like so many other gems you could try it with the same parameters from my example, try an qm_image.methods to see if .composite is there